# XSLT stylesheet relative path problem under windows

Tags: xml, windows, uri, xslt

I have a stylesheet located at /template.xsl and an xml file located at /en/index.xml, where "/" (the root) is actually of the form "C:\stuff\otherstuff\".

The xml file contains `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../template.xsl"?>`, but the stylesheet isn't detected. I've tried countless variation, using backslashes or pair or backslashes instead of slashes, using file:///, absolute path, ...

What is wrong ?

Edit : for the record, it does work in IE but not in Firefox.

Edit : and here is the explanation : http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=670995
This also include the solution :

1. type about:config in the address
   bar
2. change
   security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy
   to false

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Any input source with a PI like that, it would call a transformation in the parent folder. Do note that there are cases where you need privilege for that.

Comment: I've seen this happening when the resulting absolute path contains spaces.  What XSL transformer are you using (i.e. do you expect to be invoked) and what XML parser should invoke this transformer ?  Just MSXML ?

Comment: @Alejandro: I did not get what you meant by "calling a transformation in the parent folder".
@Alain: The path does not contain spaces. I'm simply opening the xml file with Firefox 4, so it's whatever Firefox uses. Everything works fine if xml and xslt files are placed in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that if your put template.xsl in a subdirectory say DISPLAY, href="DISPLAY/template.xsl" does work.
But if you put your XML in another subdirectory, say A, href="../DISPLAY/template.xsl" doesn't work.

It seems that there is a problem with "..".

(Even in 2015, when using Firefox 40.0 !)
See Nicholas Smethurst's attachment in :
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=439924

--> as said above, switch security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that might be the problem I think.

1. You say the files are placed in the same folder, href="../template.xsl" directs to the parent folder of your XML file. Perhaps you should use href="template.xsl". 

2. Firefox is a Beta version. If you are testing things out you should always use a stable version because otherwise it could be Beta software causing the bugs.

Comment: 1. I did not say that, template.xsl is in fact in the parent folder (please re-read my post).
2. It doesn't work in Firefox 3 either.

Answer (score -1):

If the stylesheet is called `template.xml`, as you say, then a reference to `template.xsl` isn't going to find it.